# Compact sets problem

Tags: general-topology

Find two compact subsets $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R^2}$ such that $A\times[0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $B\times [0,1]$, but $A$ is not homeomorphic to $B$. I'm really not sure where to go with this one. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you mean $A,B\subseteq\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to just tell you the answer because the point of a problem like this is to struggle a little bit. Instead, I'll give you a hint for one example: start with the square $[0,1]^2$ and add some pieces to it in two different ways. You want to choose the pieces so that it is impossible to deform one into the other in $2$-dimensional space, but so that when you take the product with $[0,1]$ and move into $3$-dimensional space one can be transformed into the other.